# Hadoop Mapreduce get job history in psuedo-distributed mode

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I am running Hadoop Mapreduce and Yarn in psuedo distributed mode and I want to get job history log. To get that, I tried solution 2 in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24390227/hadoop-jobs-fail-when-submitted-by-users-other-than-yarn-mrv2-or-mapred-mrv1) question and so, from the directory.

```
hadoop-3.0.0/bin
```

I executed

```
$ ./hdfs dfs -ls /tmp/hadoop-uname/mapred.
```

Following is what I get as response:

```
ls: `/tmp/hadoop-uname/mapred': No such file or directory
```

I get same response for:

```
$ ./hdfs dfs -ls /tmp/hadoop-uname/mapred/staging
```

also.

My questions are:

1) Are job history logs generated in psuedo history mode?

2) Is logging turned on by default? Or I need to do some other setting to turn it on?

3) Am I missing anything else?

Comment: These are local directories, not HDFS.

Comment: Is YARN log aggregation enabled? Otherwise, the log files  won't be moved to HDFS

Comment: @BenWatson Thanks. Do you know what will be the path for HDFS directories where the log files will be? 
I also looked at the following path from the file "share/doc/hadoop/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/mapred-default.xml" : <mapreduce.jobhistory.done-dir = ${yarn.app.mapreduce.am.staging-dir}/history/done = /tmp/hadoop-yarn/staging/history/done>.
I didn't find anything.

I have followed the hadoop tutorial(https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/SingleCluster.html) for the setup and have created HDFS directories given in it:

Comment: @cricket_007, this [link](https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.6.4/bk_yarn-resource-management/content/ref-375ff479-e530-46d8-9f96-8b52dadb5183.1.html) talks about enabling Yarn log aggregation. However, it says that minimum time for it is 3600 seconds. Does it mean that if I run Hadoop Map-Reduce for less than an hour, I won't get any logs?

Also, where will the aggregated logs go?

Comment: Aggregated logs go to HDFS. And if unless you wait, then the logs are only available in the NodeManager that was responsible for running the tasks

Comment: @cricket_007 Thanks. So, if I am executing in [Pseudo-Distributed](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/SingleCluster.html#Pseudo-Distributed_Operation) mode-- i.e.  resource manager and the nodes are actually on the same machine, in that case, where can I the logs of the node-manager?

Comment: On local disk, as per your own `yarn-env.sh` https://stackoverflow.com/a/48696390/2308683

Comment: @cricket_007
I looked into the yarn-env.sh In my version none of its variables are set. I searched the file and didn't find YARN_LOG_DIR, I read through the description of the variables and didn't find any which is similar to this.

On doing a grep for it I found that it is defined in the yarn-env.cmd & libexec/yarn-config.sh
Can I just define my own in yarn-env.sh, as given in your answer? 
# default log directory and file
if [ "$YARN_LOG_DIR" = "" ]; then
YARN_LOG_DIR="$HADOOP_YARN_HOME/logs"fi
YARN_OPTS="$YARN_OPTS -Dyarn.log.dir=$YARN_LOG_DIR"

Any other way to get that executed?

Comment: I believe you can, but whether that file is loaded is a different matter. I copied that code in my other answer from my local Hadoop 3.0 installation on a Mac (installed by Homebrew)